# Selinium change input value of placeholder

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hi i am trying to send input value using the sendkey command however it isn't changing.

HTML:

```
<div class="SimpleAutocomplete_autocompleteContent AutocompleteOverrides_autocompleteContent SimpleAutocomplete_opened AutocompleteOverrides_opened"><div class="SimpleAutocomplete_selectedWords AutocompleteOverrides_selectedWords"><input placeholder="" required="" value=""></div></div>
```

I have tried:

```
text = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='SimpleAutocomplete_autocompleteContent AutocompleteOverrides_autocompleteContent']"))).sendkeys("aa")
```

and

```
text = driver.find_element_by_id("placeholder").send_keys("aa")
```

all  failed

snippets of the screen :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Target the input and not the div.

Comment: care to elaborate. on that? 

i have tried : 
#text = driver.find_element_by_id("placeholder").send_keys("aa")

text = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='']"))).sendKeys("value", "aa")

and other abbreviations

Answer (score 0):

Target the input tag and not the div.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.SimpleAutocomplete_selectedWords.AutocompleteOverrides_selectedWords>input"))).sendKeys("aaa")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't change the value of placeholder, rather you send a *character sequence* to the `<input>` tag which replaces the placeholder text.

To send a *character sequence* to the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.SimpleAutocomplete_autocompleteContent.AutocompleteOverrides_autocompleteContent.SimpleAutocomplete_opened.AutocompleteOverrides_opened > div.SimpleAutocomplete_selectedWords.AutocompleteOverrides_selectedWords > input"))).send_keys("Djinn")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='SimpleAutocomplete_autocompleteContent AutocompleteOverrides_autocompleteContent SimpleAutocomplete_opened AutocompleteOverrides_opened']/div[@class='SimpleAutocomplete_selectedWords AutocompleteOverrides_selectedWords']/input"))).send_keys("Djinn")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```